# How to configure Application Request Routing in IIS 7.0 for 2 applications running different iis servers using path based routing in iis arr

Tags: iis, arr

I need path based routing in iis arr where i can create target group to assign different iis servers for web farm architecture. Which is provided by AWS Application Load Balancer.

For Example:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

I have to provide this kind of routing on my local machine using windows server IIS ARR(Application Request Routing)

Hey I need to configure this using target group which is provided by AWS ALB there is an option to set an instance in the target group for example:

[image]

I need this to be done on my local IIS machine using some third-party software.

[image]

I need something like this for my local IIS server.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want your ARR to achieve redirecting the request to the web farm according to special rule condition like http_cookie, http_host.

You could open the url rewrite rule in the IIS manamgent console and add some condition lik below image shows:

[image]

Comment: Thx for reply. I have updated my question I need a target-group for this in IIS server using URL rewrite. Where I can configure an instance, not IP.

Comment: According to the article that a target group is a set of EC2 instances, a Lambda function, or a list of IP addresses. In IIS we don't have these thing. You should build the target group by yourself. For example, you could create a web farm on the another server, then you could write the url rewrite redirect the request to that server.

Answer (score 0):

With lots of R&D, I found the answer that while crating multiple farms we can archive this 
in my scenario I want to redirect my call to a specific IP but when I am using IP address the issue is due to IP so I create Farm for each IP and redirect my call to those farm due to that my issue of IP get solved so now I don't need to configure IP address to my web config file in my project.